# Who is the wife of Karanodakshayi Vishnu and Garbhodakshayi Vishnu in the Gaudiya Vaishnava sect?

Tags: vishnu, lakshmi, gaudiya-vaishnavism, iskcon

Gaudiya Vaishnava or specially it's offshoot ISKCON has this unique three tier classification of different levels of Vishnu.

Topmost is Karanodakshayi Vishnu from whom different universes comes out of the skin pores, followed by Garbhodakshayi Vishnu who lays down at the lowest point of universal she'll to cause the birth of everything within the particular universe and the last one kshirodakshayi Vishnu who sleeps on sheshanaga in the ocean of milk on the svetadvipa island. This kshirodakshayi Vishnu has Lakshmi devi as his wife, who is portrayed massaging his feet.

I am curious about the wife name's of the other two Vishnu. Do they have a wife. Is it Lakshmi only with counterparts similar name like Karanodakshayi Lakshmi? Please answer as per Gaudiya scriptures or their official works.

Answer (score 1):

Hare Krishna

It's nothing complicated. Goddess Laksmi is the eternal consert of Narayana but in the form Karanodhaksyayi Visnu she is with Him in the form of His internal potency instead of being practically present with Him, but when He manifests Himself in the form of Ksirodhaksyayi Visnu then His internal potency gets manifested as Laksmi.

Hare Krishna

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).